# How to slice the website name from the url in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a news dataset under the dataset i have a column source where the publisher url are present but I only need the name of publisher How to slice the website name from the url in pandas dataframe

Input:

https://www.nytimes.com/2017/12/13/us/doug-jones-Alabama-black-voters.html
http://www.cnn.com/2017/12/14/us/kentucky-state-lawmaker-death/index.html

output:

nytimes
cnn

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you mean by "website name". At the moment, the examples could be taken to suggest that the website name of https://bbc.co.uk be "co", when in reality you probably want "bbc", at which point the best you can do is to parse the name against the Public Suffix List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the column name in which the data is stored is called col, try

```
df['name'] = df['col'].str.extract('www.(\w+)\.')

0    nytimes
1        cnn
```

To get them in a list

```
l = df['col'].str.extract('www.(\w+)\.').values.tolist()

['nytimes', 'cnn']
```